# Old version of index.php being served

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, caching

After updating one of my clients sites, when the page is loaded the css is missing. after further investigation i realized im getting the most current css files but an old index.php file.

I tried clearing chromes cache but that dosn't seem to change anything. On refresh the new version is served but i don't want my clients customers to have to hard refresh the page. I also tried removing the caching part of my htaccess but still no change.

Website: https://thebossattorney.com

Any help is appreciated.

.htaccess code

```
## Force SSL https ##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
## End SSL https ##

## Remove trailing slash ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://thebossattorney.com/$1 [R=301,L]
## End ##

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

## Remove page extension ##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
## End page extension ##

## error pages ##
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
## end error pages ##

## set time zone ##
SetEnv TZ America/Detroit
## end timezone ##

## Set webmaster email ##
ServerSignature EMail
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN admin@server.com
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
## End ##

## Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header ##
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
## End ##
```

Update 06/23/19: After hours of digging into this I still have not found a fix. It appears that only the index.php file is loading a cached version. Regardless of how many times i clear the browser cache on the first load i get the old version of index.php. However, all the JS and CSS files are loading the correct files. I'm going to look for a way to use Javascript to reload the page on load for the time being as a work around. Ill update here.

Comment: `ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"`. You're telling browsers to keep their cached version for a month. It's too late now, what's in the cache will remain in the cache for a month because it was instructed too.

Comment: @Capsule Gotcha. so is it being cached on the browser end or server?

Comment: Probably both as you use a CDN, but what's causing you trouble is the client side of things, as you can refresh and get the correct version, although it's not clear, your explanation seems contradictory: "I tried clearing chromes cache but that dosn't seem to change anything. On refresh the new version is served but i don't want my clients customers to have to hard refresh the page", unless by "that doesn't change anything" you meant it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Capsule im not serving the index file from a cdn. Sorry, what i meant was if i clear the cache or open a incognito window and load the site, it loads the old index.php file, but on refresh the new file is loaded. This leads me to believe its cached on the server side.

Comment: No, if the server had an old cached version, refreshing on the client side wouldn't change anything. And yes, you use a CDN, probably without knowing, as your headers say `x-cdn: Incapsula`

Comment: @Capsule ahh, my client has some sort of security on the server from bluehost. Must have to do with that. So anyone who has not cached the site who visits shouldn't experience this issue right? They would cache the latest version for 1 month?

Comment: I would assume so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue after hours of headache. It turns out Bluehost has a server side cache that they needed to clear. After they cleared the cache the server immediately started serving the new version of index.php